# compiled & installed mono 6,12,0.199 on RHEL8, vbc complains, csc succeeds

Tags: mono, rhel8, vbc

Trying to compile hello.vb:

```
Imports System

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world")
  End Sub
End Module
```

```
$ vbc hello.vb
Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 3.9.0-6.21124.20 (db94f4cc)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

vbc : error BC2017: could not find library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll'
```

However - the library file does exist under /usr/local/lib/mono/4.5-api

The same program in C#

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
  }
}
```

```
$ csc hello.cs
<elided>
$ mono hello.exe
Hello world
```

The build & install of mono was a simple

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make check
make install
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was expecting the vb compiler to work for simple programs.

Comment: When the end is drawing near, https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/, you should spend time on .NET 6/8 more than Mono. The VB.NET runtime is only available in https://github.com/mono/mono-basic and you can see it has been archived a while ago.

Comment: After a long look at it, I think gacutil creates and manipulates folders under the gac/ folder.  You can add assemblies that are strongly named, and somehow a .pdb file is also generated and stored therein.  The Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll is not strongly named, so it cannot be added, and vbc is just undermined.  If no more comments are forthcoming I will close the issue.